# Longest word in quote with Math.max

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have seen many solution which are not the way I am trying to solve this.
- I am trying to break the string at spaces and storing all the words in variable word.
I used for loop to count alphabets in every word and stored each word in alphabetsInWord one by one and pushed the length of each in array. After the loop is done, length of each word is stored in array called array. Since values in array are numbers so I want to apply Math.max on the array to find the value of logestWord but it not returning one. I have console.log statments in there to check but not necessary. Can someone please help me how to make it work. I think it will be interesting to see if works this way too.

```
    function findLongestWord(str) {
      var word = str.split(" ");
      var array=[];
      console.log(word);
         for(i=0; i <= word.length; i++){
            var alphabetsInWord = word[i];
            array.push(alphabetsInWord.length);                 
            console.log(array);
           //console.log(Math.max(array));
         }
     var longestWord = Math.max(array);
     return longesWord;
     console.log(longestWord); 

   } 

 findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` loop should not iterate to `word.length` as arrays have 0-based indexes; substitute `<` for `<=` to iterate to `word.length - 1`. Use `.apply()` with `Math.max()` which does not expect an array to be passed as parameter with `Math` set as `this`. `console.log()` will not run after `return` statement.

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var word = str.split(" ");
  var array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    var alphabetsInWord = word[i];
    array.push(alphabetsInWord.length);
  }
  var longestWord = Math.max.apply(Math, array);
  return longestWord;
}

console.log(findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

Answer (score 5):

Using ES6 syntax you can do it as follows:

```js
var str = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";

var wordLengths = str.split(" ").map(w => w.length);

const maxLength = Math.max(...wordLengths);

console.log(maxLength);
```

Alternatively you can achieve this using native `forEach()` and `sort()` methods:

```js
var str = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
var words = str.split(" ");
var wordLengths = [];

words.forEach(function(word) {
  wordLengths.push(word.length);
});
wordLengths.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});

const maxLength = wordLengths[wordLengths.length - 1];
console.log(maxLength);
```

**Use Resources:**

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Arrow functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [`Spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

---

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Thanks for all of your help! It is always interesting to look at various ways of solving one problem.